# Computing Type 3 Sum of Squares of AN(C)OVA

Tags: anova, linear-model

I have a two-way ANCOVA model of the form

$$y_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_i +\beta_j+\gamma_{ij}+\delta c_{ijk} + \epsilon_{ijk}.$$

Rewriting this model in matrix notation gives $$\boldsymbol y = \boldsymbol X\boldsymbol\theta + \boldsymbol\epsilon,$$ where $\boldsymbol X$ is the design matrix and $\boldsymbol\theta$ the vector of parameters. The model contains a constant ($\mu$), $I-1$ effects for the first factor ($\alpha_1$,$\alpha_2$,...,$\alpha_{I-1}$), $J-1$ effects for the second factor ($\beta_1$,$\beta_2$,...,$\beta_{J-1}$), $IJ - I - J+1$ interaction effects ($\gamma_1$,$\gamma_2$, ..., $\gamma_{IJ-I-J+1}$), and one effect for the confounder ($\delta$). For simplicity, we can assume that there are $N$ observations per factor level, i.e., there are $IJN$ observations in total.

I want to compute the type 3 sum of squares. I can compute the Type 3 sum of squares for the intercept, the first factor, the second factor and the confounder by $$\Vert\boldsymbol M\boldsymbol y\Vert_2^2-\Vert \boldsymbol P\boldsymbol y\Vert_2^2,$$ where $\boldsymbol P = \boldsymbol I_{IJN} - \boldsymbol X(\boldsymbol X^\top\boldsymbol X)^{-1}\boldsymbol X$ and $\boldsymbol M = \boldsymbol I_{IJN} - \boldsymbol V(\boldsymbol V^\top\boldsymbol V)^{-1}\boldsymbol V$ with $\boldsymbol V$ being given by $\boldsymbol X$

- with the first column deleted,
- with the columns associated with the first factor deleted,
- with the columns associated with the second factor deleted, and
- with the column associated with the confounder deleted,

respectively. However, I can't obtain the sum of squares for the interaction term this way. My question is thus how can I compute the Type 3 sum of squares for the interaction term, preferably using matrix notation.